# Index issue creating a counter in python

Tags: python

What I want to do is a counter of 0 values in a list.
I'm trying to make a counter using python, but it seems it is not working.
I need to have the final list count with all the values.

My code is:

```
count=[0,0,0,0,0]  #counter
mylist=[0.9971989983534086, 0.9855488723192819, 0, 0.979924988605467, 0.9740293465156515]

for V in mylist:

    J=mylist.index(V) #J is the index of V 
    if V==0:
        count[J] = count[J] + 1

print count
```

As results I have:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

The problem is when I have 2 zeros on mylist:

```
count=[0,0,0,0,0]  #counter
mylist=[0.9971989983534086, 0.9855488723192819, 0, 0.979924988605467, 0]

for V in mylist:

    J=mylist.index(V)
    if V==0:
        count[J] = count[J] + 1

print count
```

The results is: 
`[0, 0, 2, 0, 0]` instead of `[0, 0, 1, 0, 1]`

It looks like it takes always the same J if V==0.

Any idea to fix it ?

Comment: Getting the index with `mylist.index(V)` returns the index of the _first_ occurrence of `0`. It's always going to be the same spot, hence why the same number is being incremented. Also, your code could be replaced with `print([int(a == 0) for a in mylist])`, which produces `[0, 0, 1, 0, 1]`.

Comment: If you are iterating over `mylist` and you want to get the index of `V`, why not just use `for i, V in enumerate(myList)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
count=[0,0,0,0,0]  #counter
mylist=[0.9971989983534086, 0.9855488723192819, 0, 0.979924988605467, 0]

for i, V in enumerate(mylist):
    if V==0:
        count[i] += 1

print count
```

Answer (score 1):

`index()` will only give you the position in the list of the first instance of `0`. Instead you can create a list comprehension that will iterate the whole list once and create a `1` every time the item in that list is equal to zero.

```
mylist = [0.9971989983534086, 0.9855488723192819, 0, 0.979924988605467, 0.9740293465156515, 0]
counter = [1 if item == 0 else 0 for item in mylist]
print counter
```

Answer (score 0):

mylist.index(V) returns the index of the first occurrence (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html), a quick fix would be :

```
J=0
for V in mylist:
    if V==0:
        count[J] = count[J] + 1
    J = J + 1
```